# best way to create an addon to firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, wiki

what are the programming skills need to create a firefox addon......

i googled it and found these links

http://roachfiend.com/archives/2004/12/0…
http://lifehacker.com/software/programmi…
Source(s):
http://roachfiend.com/archives/2004/12/0…
http://lifehacker.com/software/programmi…

anybody please help me in figuring the best way.....

Comment: We don't deal in subjective questions. If you haven't already, please check out the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XUL School: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_School